# React SVG component with color as props

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have a singular problem with SVG.
I did two different components with svg code with possibility to change color with props. Now when I call both components they have the same color depended on call order. 
At first I was thinking it's because props has the same 'name' but no. I tried wrap these component to separate them but also doesn't work.

Here I did simplified version of this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-triangle-with-colos-as-prop-njmy7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

One more thing. If you inspect these svg they have different colors. I really don't what is going on.

Greetings and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-triangle-with-colos-as-prop-0k8yw

I think it's because you're defining two `linearGradient`s with the same ID and referencing the same ID in each triangle.

You'll probably want to extract out a component that generates a unique ID (could just be a counter) that you can reference, or somehow generate a unique ID for everything that has an ID (the filters, for example).

Comment: @y'ffre  I've been doing a lot of SVG work lately for a side project and SVG makes me feel stupid a *lot* :)